# Free spam blocker service

Tags: spam, spam-blocker, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent spam on sites which I control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control)

Is it possible to get a free and good spam blocker for your website?

I would really like to avoid having to serve CAPTCHAs to my site's users, but I don't want spam bots to be able to post links etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Akismet](http://akismet.com/) is free for personal use. It's from the makers of WordPress and will work with many platforms. There are [libraries](http://akismet.com/development/) available for Python, PHP, ColdFusion, .Net, etc.

Comment: You can also use bad behavior, another popular wordpress plug-in with your own code. A lot of bots tend to make lousy HTTP requests, the best way to stop them is make sure they never see the form. Combined with Akismet, its very effective. I may be suggesting a bit more programming work than is appropriate for this site, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the third party solution that is [disqus](http://disqus.com). It provides spam protection, moderation, and supports logins of openid, facebook, twitter, and their own disqus accounts.

Comment: I get nervous not controlling all my data, but this service does work.

Answer (score 0):

A good and simple honey pot technique was proposed in the question [Effective captcha solutions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/194/effective-captcha-solutions/201#201).